# Azure Devops Container Job - Authenticate with ACR and pull an image

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I got a custom image uploaded to my ACR. When I reference the images within my pipeline the authentication to the ACR fails and the pipeline is unable to pull the image.

How do I authenticate with ACR and pull images via a pipeline:

Example code:

```
parameters:
  - name: App_VariableGroup
    type: string
    default: my-defaults
    values:
      - my-defaults

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

container: myacr.azurecr.io/customubuntu:latest

variables:
  - group: ${{ parameters.App_VariableGroup }}

steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
- script: | 
    echo Hello, world! \n 
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create a Service Connection:

My Project --> Project Settings --> Pipelines --> Service connections --> New Service Connection --> Docker --> Docker registry --> Azure Container Registry  --> Authenticate and provide a Service Connection name "my-acr-service-connection-name"

Then go to Project --> Pipelines --> Library --> Variable Groups --> My Variable Group --> add the following:

```
name: containerRegistryServiceConnection
value: my-acr-service-connection-name
```

Then update your YAML file as below:

```
container: 
  image: myacr.azurecr.io/customubuntu:latest
  endpoint: my-acr-service-connection-name
```

This should allow you to run a VM with Docker container on it.

Comment: Please mark your answer as a correct one so that others who meet the same issue will find your excellent solution to help them. We will appreciate your good job on helping us make the work better and easier.